# How to present view controller with one view controller alreadly be presented?

Tags: ios, presentviewcontroller

Just like when you write new mail with iOS native mail app.
or you ask new-question with stackoverflow iOS app.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Just present the new view controller from the top-most presented view controller.

Comment: Have you try any code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to present your new **ViewController**, with helper method

```
extension UIApplication {
  class func topViewController(base: UIViewController? = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).window?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
      return topViewController(base: nav.visibleViewController)
    }
    if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
      if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
        return topViewController(base: selected)
      }
    }
    if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
      return topViewController(base: presented)
    }
    return base
  }
}
```

Call the above helper method from your ViewController like

```
UIApplication.topViewController().present(vc2, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you! Find the top view controller and use it to present  another one. I know this way , but it is not what I want .